# Finding out the minimum difference between elements in an array

Tags: algorithm

I have an integer array with some finite number of values. My job is to find the minimum difference between any two elements in the array.

Consider that the array contains

```
4, 9, 1, 32, 13
```

Here the difference is minimum between 4 and 1 and so answer is 3.

What should be the algorithm to approach this problem. Also, I don't know why but I feel that using trees, this problem can be solved relatively easier. Can that be done?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Comment: You mean you are solving this http://www.codechef.com/SEP12/problems/HORSES

Comment: Yup.. I asked this question based on that !!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The minimum difference will be one of the differences from among the consecutive pairs in sorted order. Sort the array, and go through the pairs of adjacent numbers looking for the smallest difference:

```
int[] a = new int[] {4, 9, 1, 32, 13};
Arrays.sort(a);
int minDiff = a[1]-a[0];
for (int i = 2 ; i != a.length ; i++) {
    minDiff = Math.min(minDiff, a[i]-a[i-1]);
}
System.out.println(minDiff);
```

[This prints `3`.](http://ideone.com/vMu8Y)

Comment: Okay.. I get what you are saying. But sorting itself will take O(n.log n) time. I'm just curious, but can we do without sorting !!

Comment: @CSSS if you do a radix sort it is *O(n)*

Comment: @CSSS I don't think you can do it faster than `O(N*LogN)`. You have to go through elements of the array at least once, and for each element you'll need to find its best "counterpart" for subtraction. The best you can do there is `Log(N)` if you use a tree.

Comment: Please can you throw some light on how to use a tree here !!

Comment: @CSSS Walk the array, and build a binary search tree from its elements. Every time you add a node to your BST, check the difference between the newly added element and each of the nodes that you walk while finding the place of the new element in the tree. The counterpart with the smallest difference will be among one of these nodes. Inserting a node in a tree takes `Log(N)`, for a total of `O(N*Log(N)).`

Comment: Yea, building a binary search tree is just another flavour of sorting in reality.

Answer (score 14):

You can take advantage of the fact that you are considering integers
to make a linear algorithm:

1. First pass:
   compute the maximum and the minimum
2. Second pass:
   allocate a boolean array of length (max - min + 1), false initialized, 
   and change the (value -  min)th value to true for every value in the array
3. Third pass:
   compute the differences between the indexes of the true valued entries of the boolean array.

Comment: This is linear in `N`, but also gets a linear dependency on `max-min` which can make it pretty bad.

Answer (score 7):

While all the answers are correct, I wanted to show the underlying algorithm responsible for `n log n` run time. The *divide and conquer* way of finding the minimum distance between the two points or finding the closest points in a 1-D plane.

The general algorithm:

[image]

- Let m = median(S).
- Divide S into S1, S2 at m.
- δ1 = Closest-Pair(S1).
- δ2 = Closest-Pair(S2).
- δ12 is minimum distance across the cut.
- Return δ = min(δ1, δ2, δ12).

Here is a sample I created in Javascript:

```js
// Points in 1-D
var points = [4, 9, 1, 32, 13];

var smallestDiff;

function mergeSort(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 1)
    return arr;

  if (arr.length > 1) {
    let breakpoint = Math.ceil((arr.length / 2));
    // Left list starts with 0, breakpoint-1
    let leftList = arr.slice(0, breakpoint);
    // Right list starts with breakpoint, length-1
    let rightList = arr.slice(breakpoint, arr.length);

    // Make a recursive call
    leftList = mergeSort(leftList);
    rightList = mergeSort(rightList);

    var a = merge(leftList, rightList);
    return a;
  }
}

function merge(leftList, rightList) {
  let result = [];
  while (leftList.length && rightList.length) {
    // Sorting the x coordinates
    if (leftList[0] <= rightList[0]) {
      result.push(leftList.shift());
    } else {
      result.push(rightList.shift());
    }
  }

  while (leftList.length)
    result.push(leftList.shift());

  while (rightList.length)
    result.push(rightList.shift());

  let diff;
  if (result.length > 1) {
    diff = result[1] - result[0];
  } else {
    diff = result[0];
  }

  if (smallestDiff) {
    if (diff < smallestDiff)
      smallestDiff = diff;
  } else {
    smallestDiff = diff;
  }
  return result;
}

mergeSort(points);

console.log(`Smallest difference: ${smallestDiff}`);
```

Answer (score 5):

I would put them in a heap in `O(nlogn)` then pop one by one and get the minimum difference between every element that I pop. Finally I would have the minimum difference. However, there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a restatement of the `closest-pair` problem in `one-dimension`.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem 
http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/grant/cp.pdf

As the Wikipedia article cited below points out, the best decision-tree model of this problem also runs in `Ω(nlogn)` time.

Answer (score 2):

sharing the simplest solution.

```
function FindMin(arr) {

    //sort the array in increasing order

    arr.sort((a,b) => {
       return a-b;
    });

    let min = arr[1]-arr[0];

    let n = arr.length;

    for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {

      let m = arr[i+1] - arr[i];
      if(m < min){
        m = min;
      }
    }

    return m; // minimum difference.
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The given problem can easily be solved in O(n) time. Look at the following code that I wrote.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Solution {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, minDistance = 999999;
        boolean flag = false;
        int capacity = input.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[capacity];
        for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            arr[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        int firstElement = input.nextInt();
        int secondElement = input.nextInt();

        int prev = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == firstElement || arr[i] == secondElement) {
                prev = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (; i < capacity; i++) {
            if(arr[i] == firstElement || arr[i] == secondElement) {
                if(arr[i] != arr[prev] && minDistance > Math.abs(i - prev)) {
                    minDistance = Math.abs(i - prev);
                    flag = true;
                    prev = i;
                } else {
                    prev = i;
                }
            }
        }

        if(flag)
            System.out.println(minDistance);
        else
            System.out.println("-1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer would have been much better if you had explained the logic behind your algorithm instead of providing the code without any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who are looking for a one-line [python](/questions/tagged/python) answer (more or less), these are 2 possible solutions:

#### Python >= 3.10

```
l = sorted([4, 9, 1, 32, 13])
min(map(lambda x: x[1] - x[0], pairwise(l)))
```

From Python 3.10 you can use [`pairwise()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) that takes an iterable and returns all consecutive pairs of it. After we sort the initial list, we just need to find the pair with the minimum difference.

---

#### Python < 3.10

```
l = sorted([4, 9, 1, 32, 13])
min(map(lambda x: x[1] - x[0], zip(l[:-1], l[1:])))
```

In this case, we can reproduce the `pairwise()` method behavior<sup>1</sup> using `zip()` with 2 slices of the same list so that consecutive elements are paired.

---

<sub>1. The actual implementation of `pairwise()` is probably more efficient in terms of space because it doesn't need to create 2 (shallow) copies of the list. In most cases, this should not be necessary, but you can use `itertools.islice` to iterate over the list without creating a copy of it. Then, you would write something like `zip(islice(a, len(a) - 1), islice(a, 1, None))`.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

In Python 3 this problem can be simplified by using the module **itertools** which gives the combinations available for a list. From that list we can find the sum of each combination and find the minimum of those values.

```
import itertools

arr = [4, 9, 1, 32, 13]

if len(arr) > 1:
    min_diff = abs(arr[0] - arr[1])
else:
    min_diff = 0

for n1, n2 in itertools.combinations(arr, 2): # Get the combinations of numbers
    diff = abs(n1-n2) # Find the absolute difference of each combination
    if min_diff > diff:
        min_diff = diff # Replace incase a least differnce found

print(min_diff)
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, a little explanation could improve the answer's long term value.

Comment: @jrook Updated the answer to give an explanation.

Comment: The comments mix `absolute difference` and `minimum of sum`. A list with about `len(arr)`² elements is constructed in a "non-pythonic" way.

Comment: @greybeard Edited the answer to avoid using list. What about this one ?

Comment: What is the complexity? If you examine all combinations, then it is O(n^2), therefore much slower that other answers

Comment: [Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232930/finding-out-the-minimum-difference-between-elements-in-an-array/59056657?noredirect=1#comment104372151_59056657) is bang on right: O(n²) time (one might stop once min_diff turns 0). A saving grace might be O(1) extra space without modifying the input.