# Efficient way to find a pair with minimum difference in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting, computational-geometry

I'm trying to solve a problem that requires me to find a pair with minimum difference in an array.

For example, if the array is

```
6,7,1,3,9
```

The output is

```
(6,7)
```

with difference of 1 which is minimum.

The fastest solution I can come up with is to sort the array and iterate through the sorted array to find the minimum difference [O(nlogn)]. Is there a way to optimise this or better solve it in O(n) or O(logn)?

Edit: All elements of the array are distinct.

Comment: Is the array always discrete and distinct? i.e. Would you ever get [1,2,3,2] or  [1,2,1.5,1.56]?

Comment: Yes. All elements are distinct.

Comment: If so, you would at least be able to halt the iteration at the first difference of 1. That's all I've got at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. That's an optimisation to the current solution.

Comment: Nice. I've added it as an answer with a couple of links.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all numbers are distinct and secrete, you can stop your search once the difference is 1.

There is also a wikipedia article on this problem here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Also another question here: [Finding out the minimum difference between elements in an arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232930/finding-out-the-minimum-difference-between-elements-in-an-arrays)

My improvement:

```
int[] a = new int[] {4, 9, 1, 32, 13};
Arrays.sort(a);
int minDiff = a[1]-a[0];
for (int i = 2 ; i != a.length ; i++) {
    minDiff = Math.min(minDiff, a[i]-a[i-1]);
    if (minDif == 1)
        break;
}
System.out.println(minDiff);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect you can find a `O(log n)` solution as there is at least a need to iterate over a whole array to see its elements. For me the sorting approach seems optimal but there is a possibility to improve the `O(n log n)` complexity if your numbers are from a not so big set which is known before (e.g. integers from the range `[0; N]` for some quite small `N`). In such case you could use the counting sort algorithm for which the worst-case complexity is `O(n + N)`. However, please note that the space usage is also `O(n + N)`. There are many sources on the counting sort and this one should be sufficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve the [Closest Pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) problem, in which you search for the two points in your dataset that have the minimum distance from each other. Setting the dimension to 1 reduces to your case (a point is just a number).

The time complexity of the algorithms solving this problem efficiently is:

> O(nlogn)

Note that Divide and Conquer techniques can be used in this context. As for example in these [slides](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~bai/ECS122A/Closestpair.pdf).

Tip: If you assume that the data points are *distinct*, then you can stop your algorithm when you find a distance of 1 (since it cannot be less than 1), but this might not ever be the case for your data.